# Way of understanding recursion properly (javascript)

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to understand recursion and I have a somewhat decent understanding on how it intuitively works, however the aggregation of the returned data is the bit I struggle with.

For instance, in javascript to flatten an array I came up with the following code:

```
var _flatten = function(arr){
    if(!arr instanceof Array) return arr;
    var g = [];

   function flatten(arr){

     for(var i = 0; i < arr.length;i++){
         if(arr[i] instanceof Array){
         flatten(arr[i]);
         }else{
         g.push(arr[i]);
        }
     }
   }

  flatten(arr);
  return g;
}
```

Turning something like this

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,[1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]];
```

into this:`[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`

Which is fine and all, but the global variable g seems like some kind of cheap hack. I don't know how to think about the result returned when getting to the top of the stack and the return of the function propagating back down the stack. How would you implement this function, and how can I get a better grasp on this?

Thanks!

Comment: check the `java` tag, `java` is not `javascript`

Comment: For complex recursion like that, I would simplify the problem (make it smaller), instead of working with `[1,2,3,4,5,6,[1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]]` you can simplify it like `[1,2,[1,2,3]]` and from there try to understand how the here recursion works.

Comment: `g` isn't global, using closures in JavaScript is a perfectly fine approach.

Comment: Sorry, I meant global to the function and outside the for loop where it would be reinitialised on every iteration.

Comment: To understand recursion properly, [please refer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076605/way-of-understanding-recursion-properly-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many ways to write an array flattening procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025/633183) but I understand your question is about understanding recursion in general

The `g` isn't global in *any* sense of the word, but it is a symptom of the implementation choices. Mutation isn't necessarily bad so long as you keep it localized to your function – that `g` is never leaked outside of the function where someone could potentially observe the side effects.

Personally tho, I think it's better to break your problem into small generic procedures that make it much easier to describe your code.

You'll note that we don't have to setup temporary variables like `g` or handle incrementing array iterators like `i` – we don't even have to look at the `.length` property of the array. Not having to think about these things make it really nice to write our program in a declarative way.

```js
// concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
const concatMap = f => xs => xs.map(f).reduce((x,y) => x.concat(y), [])

// id :: a -> a
const id = x => x

// flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const flatten = concatMap (id)

// isArray :: a -> Bool
const isArray = Array.isArray

// deepFlatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const deepFlatten = concatMap (x => isArray(x) ? deepFlatten(x) : x)

// your sample data
let data = [0, [1, [2, [3, [4, 5], 6]]], [7, [8]], 9]

console.log(deepFlatten(data))
// [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

console.log(flatten(data))
// [ 0, 1, [ 2, [ 3, [ 4, 5 ], 6 ] ], 7, [ 8 ], 9 ]
```

First you'll see I made two different flattening procedures. `flatten` to flatten one level of nesting, and `deepFlatten` to flatten an arbitrarily deep array.

You'll also see I use `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` since these are provided by ECMAScript but that doesn't mean you're only limited to using procedures that you have. You can make your own procedures to fill the gaps. Here we made `concatMap` which is a useful generic provided by other languages such as Haskell.

Utilizing these generics, you can see that `deepFlatten` is an insanely simple procedure.

```
// deepFlatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
const deepFlatten = concatMap (x => isArray(x) ? deepFlatten(x) : x)
```

It's made up of a single expression including a lambda made up of a single `if` branch (by use of the ternary operator `?:`)

---

Maybe it's a lot to take in, but hopefully it demonstrates that "writing a recursive procedure" isn't always about complicated setup of state variables and complex logic to control the recursion. In this case, it's a simple

```
if (condition) recurse else don't
```

If you have any questions, let me know. I'm happy to help you in any way I can.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a global variable (to make it more proper recursion) you can send in g as a argument to the flatten function, and pass the modified g back out with a return statement.

```
var _flatten = function(arr) {
  if (!arr instanceof Array) return arr;

  function flatten(arr, g) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] instanceof Array) {
        flatten(arr[i], g);
      } else {
        g.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return g;
  }

  return flatten(arr, []);
}
```

Comment: That sounds wise. Would I have to return anything in that case, or would the g passed in point to the user created array?

Comment: You could return g, as in my recent edit. Otherwise you could just replace the array with the array with the resulting items, saving the argument. That would be more in line with the "design pattern" recursion, I think.

Comment: Also, this code is more or less an example of the "reduce" operation.

Answer (score 1):

In fact recursive coding is very simple and every aspects of it shall be contained in the function body. Any info that needs to pass shall be sent through arguments to the next recursion. Usage of global thingies is very ugly and shall be avoided. Accordingly i would simply do the in place array flattening job as follows;

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,[1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3],[1,2,[9,8,7],3,4]]];

function flatArray(arr){
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
    Array.isArray(arr[i]) && (arr.splice(i,0,...flatArray(arr.splice(i,1)[0])), len = arr.length);
  return arr;
}

console.log(flatArray(list));
```

Comment: @Eladian It's actuall very simple. It just iterates through the array. If it meets an array item (`Array.isArray(arr[i])` is true) it does the following in sequence... Take it off from the array (`arr.splice(i,1)[0]`) and send it recursivelly to flat array (`flatArray(arr.splice(i,1)[0])`) and then insert the returned flat array to the same index location by spreading it (`...` spread operator) (`arr.splice(i,0,...flatArray(arr.splice(i,1)[0])`)